# React Native infinite loop with object array in useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, infinite-loop

In my project, I need to get selected items from a Flatlist and pass them to my parent component.

I created a local state like this:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState<IStateType[] | []>([])
```

Each time an item is selected I try to add it to my useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const result = myState.filter((el) => el.id !== item.id)
    if (isSelected) {
      setMyState([
        ...result,
        {
          propOne: 0,
          propTwo: 1,
          id: item.id,
         ...
        },
      ])
    } else {
      setMyState(result)
    }
  }, [isSelected])
```

But I would need to put mySate in the dependency of my useEffect to add each time the new items selected. If I add it to the useEffect dependency it causes an infinite loop ^^
How to add each new item to my array while listening to all the changes and without causing an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having it's because you're not separating the concerns of each component correctly, once you have to relay on the previous data every time, the `useEffect` can be tricky. But there are two solutions to your issue:

#### Make use of `useState` callback function:

The `useState` function can be used with a callback rather than a value, as follows:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (isSelected) {
      setMyState(prevState => [
        ...prevState,
        {
          propOne: 0,
          propTwo: 1,
          id: item.id,
         ...
        },
      ])
    } else {
      setMyState(result)
    }
  }, [isSelected])
```

#### Best structure of your components + using `useState` callback function

What I could see about your approach is that you (as you showed) seems to be trying to handle the `isSelected` for each item and the `myState` in the same component, which could be done, but it's non-ideal. So I propose the creation of two components, let's say:

- `<List />`: Should handle the callback for selecting an item and rendering them.

`<List />`:

```
function List() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);

  const isItemSelected = useCallback(
    (itemId) => myState.some((el) => el.id === itemId),
    [myState]
  );

  const handleSelectItem = useCallback(
    (itemId) => {
      const isSelected = isItemSelected(itemId);

      if (isSelected) {
        setMyState((prevState) => prevState.filter((el) => el.id !== itemId));
      } else {
        setMyState((prevState) => prevState.concat({ id: itemId }));
      }
    },
    [isItemSelected]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{renderTimes ?? 0}</p>

      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          item={item}
          onSelectItem={handleSelectItem}
          selected={isItemSelected(item.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

- `<Item />`: Should handle the `isSelected` field internally for each item.

`<Item />`:

```
const Item = ({ item, selected = false, onSelectItem }) => {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsSelected(selected);
  }, [selected]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {item.name} is {isSelected ? "selected" : "not selected"}
      </p>
      <button onClick={() => onClick(item.id)}>
        {isSelected ? "Remove" : "Select"} this item
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here's a [codesnack](https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-useeffect-infinite-loop-ebmovz?file=/src/App.js) where I added a function that counts the renders, so you can check the performance of your solution.

Comment: indeed, I decentered the state in a parent component and the listitem is only the list item ;)